# error while reading json data present as blob in GCP. error: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to read , loop through the json data and fetch values associated with **table_name** and **schema**
from google storage bucket in python but getting below error. Can anyone help why this error is coming and how to modify these code

```
file content: ABC.json
 data = '{
    "table_name": "abc.dataset.table1",
    "schema": [
               bigquery.SchemaField("COL1", "STRING"),
              ]
        }'

 blob = bucket.blob('delta/path/ABC.json')
       downloaded_blob = blob.download_as_string() 
       downloaded_blob = downloaded_blob.decode("utf-8")
       print(downloaded_blob)
       data = json.loads(downloaded_blob)
       print(data)
       print(data['table_name'])


error :raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: What does your json looks like, can you add in the question ?

Comment: file content :ABC.json shows content of json

Comment: yes but how does json look like, please add json in the question

Answer (score 2):

The reason seems to be the fact that your `ABC.json` is not actually valid JSON.
In the `schema` key, there's this :

```
[
    bigquery.SchemaField("COL1", "STRING"),
]
```

JSON only allows certain [types](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_datatypes.asp), and this `bigquery.SchemaField` literal is not one of them.

Comment: Thanks @icebreaker454.  json file was corrected  and issue is resolved